# How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tooltip

I have a series of svg rectangles (using D3.js) and I want to display a message on mouseover, the message should be surrounded by a box that acts as background. They should both be perfectly aligned to each other and to the rectangle (on top and centered). What is the best way to do this?

I tried adding an svg text using the "x", "y", "width" and "height" attributes, and then prepending an svg rect. The problem is that the reference point for the text is in the middle (since I want it centered aligned I used `text-anchor: middle`), but for the rectangle it's the top left coordinate, plus I wanted a bit of margin around the text which makes it kind of a pain.

The other option was using an html div, which would be nice, because I can add the text and padding directly but I don't know how to get the absolute coordinates for each rectangle. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If there's no other way, I guess

Comment: Is that a problem, using markup for what it was designed for?

Comment: It's just that it doesn't look as nice, but I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the title element as Phrogz indicated. There are also some good tooltips like jQuery's Tipsy http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/ (which can be used to replace all title elements), Bob Monteverde's nvd3 or even the Twitter's tooltip from their Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 223):

Can you use simply the [SVG `<title>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements) and the default browser rendering it conveys? (Note: this is **not** the same as the `title` attribute you can use on div/img/spans in html, it needs to be a child *element* named `title`)

```css
rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: #69c;
  stroke: #069;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<p>Mouseover the rect to see the tooltip on supporting browsers.</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to show HTML in your SVG, you can embed HTML directly:

```css
rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: #69c;
  stroke: #069;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

foreignObject {
  width: 100%;
}

svg div {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect/>
  <foreignObject>
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>
        Hello, <b>World</b>!
      </div>
    </body>      
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

…but then you'd need JS to turn the display on and off. As shown above, one way to make the label appear at the right spot is to wrap the rect and HTML in the same `<g>` that positions them both together.

To use JS to find where an SVG element is on screen, you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`, e.g. http://phrogz.net/svg/html_location_in_svg_in_html.xhtml

Comment: Nice answer. But please note that `foreignObject` [is not supported in Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#search=foreignObject)

Comment: On Firefox the SVG has size 0x0? It seems like you have to specify width and height like `<rect width="200" height="50"></rect>`

Comment: Unfortunately `<title>` has no effect on mobile devices.

Comment: When I am trying to add the title using js, and appending title as the child element. The tooltip is not appearing :(

Comment: For the foreign object element on Chromium 79 I needed to set height attribute to get it to display. But nice approach!

Comment: I don't see any tooltip for your second example in Chrome 80

Answer (score 79):

The only good way I found was to use Javascript to move a tooltip `<div>` around. Obviously this only works if you have SVG inside an HTML document - not standalone. And it requires Javascript.

```js
function showTooltip(evt, text) {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = text;
  tooltip.style.display = "block";
  tooltip.style.left = evt.pageX + 10 + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = evt.pageY + 10 + 'px';
}

function hideTooltip() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#tooltip {
  background: cornsilk;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tooltip" display="none" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>

<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="50" style="fill: blue;" onmousemove="showTooltip(evt, 'This is blue');" onmouseout="hideTooltip();" >
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

I always go with the generic css title with my setup. I'm just building analytics for my blog admin page. I don't need anything fancy. Here's some code...

```
let comps = g.selectAll('.myClass')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   ...styling...
   ...transitions...
   ...whatever...

g.selectAll('.myClass')
   .append('svg:title')
   .text((d, i) => d.name + '-' + i);
```

And a screenshot of chrome...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I came up with something using HTML + CSS only. Hope it works for you

```css
.mzhrttltp {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mzhrttltp .hrttltptxt {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #040505;
  font-size:13px;color:#fff;font-family:IranYekanWeb;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 105%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.mzhrttltp .hrttltptxt::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #040505 transparent;
}

.mzhrttltp:hover .hrttltptxt {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="mzhrttltp"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#e2062c" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-heart"><path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z"></path></svg><div class="hrttltptxt">علاقه&zwnj;مندی&zwnj;ها</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did it with Bootstrap 4.

The span allows the tool tip to be clear, instead of using a button.

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The text of the tooltip goes here">
                        
--- SVG element goes here ---
                    
</span>
```

I had to activate all the tooltips in the page by addig this jquery code:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```