# add tooltip in stacked bar chart D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

Could you please help me in adding tooltip in stacked Bar chart. I have created Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9UfT2/3/.)

i want to add tool tip on each bar chart ie. Each bar should show tool tip for each color. How can i do that.

```
> NA
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a `title` element under each `rect` and give it a text value of whatever you want the tooltip to say.

Here's a related question showing more details: [How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Looks doable, will try that

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to show on tool tip? Is it data value or some text?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
                  .append("svg:title")
                  .text(function(d){
                    return yourData;    
                      }
                  });
```

This function should work for you and put the variable name where you are getting corresponding values of bars.