# SVG Rectangle display HTML title on mouseover

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip, rectangles

I try to display a tooltip on mouse hover a rectangle. My attempt were using `<g>` and set a `title` to it and set a `title` to the `<rect>` itself but does not produce any visible output (*on Chrome*).

**HTML**

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <g title="blue rectangle">
    <rect width="50px" height="50px" fill="blue" x="10px" y="10px"></rect>
  </g>
  <rect width="50px" height="50px" fill="red" x="60px" y="60px" title="red rectangle"></rect>
</svg>
```

**OBSERVATION**

Thanks to **@Jacob Gray** comment, the problem remains on Chrome (FireFox behaves correctly).

Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Comment: works for me in firefox 42

Comment: You totally right @JacobGray, I did not tryied it on FF. Seems a Chrome issue (currently using Chrome 47.0).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two methods: using the recommended `<title></title>` **element**, and the discouraged `title` **attribute**.

The use of the `title` **attribute** is discouraged in the [**W3C spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-title-attribute). It even comes with a warning.

> **Warning!**
>
> Relying on the title attribute is currently discouraged as many user agents do not expose the attribute in an accessible manner as required by this specification (e.g. requiring a pointing device such as a mouse to cause a tooltip to appear, which excludes keyboard-only users and touch-only users, such as anyone with a modern phone or tablet).

---

However, as mentioned in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic/10643523#10643523) by [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz), SVG actually has an element for that.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title): SVG `<title>` element

> Each container element or graphics element in an SVG drawing can supply a title description string where the description is text-only. When the current SVG document fragment is rendered as SVG on visual media, title element is not rendered as part of the graphics. However, some user agents may, for example, display the title element as a tooltip. Alternate presentations are possible, both visual and aural, which display the title element but do not display path elements or other graphics elements. The title element generally improve accessibility of SVG documents

[**W3C SVG Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements) `<desc>` & `<title>` elements

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <g>
    <title>blue rectangle</title>
    <rect width="50px" height="50px" fill="blue" x="10px" y="10px"></rect>

  </g>
  <rect width="50px" height="50px" fill="red" x="60px" y="60px" title="red rectangle"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok so should we understand Firefox behaves consistently with HTML **and** SVG elements, which is not correct ? By the way thank you for your input.

Comment: If FF displays a title attribute on SVG elements it is wrong to do so. tooltips should come from a title child element. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: No idea if the title **attribute** displays in FF for SVG (I haven't checked and...can't test at the moment.)

Comment: @Zeratops I've raised [bug 1235066](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1235066) for Firefox. SVG elements should only display title child elements as tooltips. They do not use title attributes as html does

Comment: While this is indeed the best approach, it seems that these tooltips are never displayed when you are using <use> to display the rect element.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the erroneous display of the title attribute for SVG elements in Firefox [from version 46](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1235066) onwards.

Chrome and Firefox will now behave the same, they will both require child `<title>` elements for SVG tooltips. Note that there's no change there, both UAs have worked this way for many many releases now.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your concern and your time to give this issue a fix.