# SVG use element tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, svg, tooltip

Is it possible to have the [< use >](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwjqa3vavMAhXBkZQKHRbSAmMQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FSVG%2FElement%2Fuse&usg=AFQjCNECleyAXJuFtanFxBgujUxZz_pGpg&sig2=CE_hMcKWzQ5Ym0WHIKqxwA&bvm=bv.120551593,d.dGo) element display the rect tooltip, on mouse over, with modern browsers?

As specified by [15.2.1 The hint element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/applications.html).

```
<svg id="schematic" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="pnp-transistor">
        <image xlink:href="transistor.png" height="32px" width="32px" />

        <rect y="0" x="0" height="6px" width="32px">
            <title>collector</title>
            <hint>collector</hint>
        </rect>

        <rect y="27" x="0" height="6px" width="32px">
            <title>emitter</title>
            <hint>emitter</hint>
        </rect>

        <rect y="0" x="0" height="32px" width="6px">
            <title>base</title>
            <hint>base</hint>
        </rect>
    </symbol>

    <use xlink:href="#pnp-transistor"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you mean like creating a custom Angular directive called <use> that would fire off an event to show a tooltip with this SVG image?

Comment: Nope, SVG use element; see above.

Comment: Only via some custom javascript which would copy the title into the use as a child element.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no way to do this without JavaScript, using `getBoundingClientRect()` to location the position of the SVG in the DOM. Good stuff in here: [How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic). Even then, I'm not sure how well supported and easy to style that direction would be.

However, a possible workaround is to add another wrapper around symbol and tie CSS into it when hovering on the pseudoclass. Using `attr(data-tooltip)` is not as nice as using content directly inherited by the symbol, but it's not a terrible second place.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-tooltip="SVG Tooltip (almost)">
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#some-id"></use></svg>  
</div>
```

...

```
.wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.wrapper:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0.5em);
}
```

[image]

Codepen: [SVG With Pure CSS Tooltip](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/mPGBpW)