# React-Tooltip not working inside SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add `React-Tooltip` to my `React` app, and when I just statically add `data-tip="hello world"` to an element, it is working, however, when I append the attribute to an element inside of `svg` it is not. I see that the attribute is added inside `html`:

[image]

But hovering over the element does not show the tooltip. I am using collapsible tree code:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

And trying to make tooltip working like that:

```
node.attr("data-tip", "helloworld");
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this might help https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/306

Answer (score 3):

I have recently open-sourced [react-svg-tooltip](https://github.com/netzwerg/react-svg-tooltip), a React component to create tooltips for SVG elements. It is still wet from birth, but maybe you still find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show tooltip inside SVG you can have look on following link:
[How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic)