# Angular - Add tooltip to SVG element

Tags: angular, svg, tooltip

I have an SVG element on my web site:

```
<ellipse id="svg_2" cy="78.999999" cx="1042.499999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
```

I want to add tooltip to this element. I tried NGPrime and NGX-bootstrap but tooltip does not show on this element (it works when I add this to any other element on my web site).

I'm working with Angular 4 CLI.

Any ide how I can acheive that?

Comment: You can add a `<title>` child element, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10643523/1009922), and as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3nc1c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Don't think it's a duplicate as this is specific to Angular.

Comment: The `<title>` does not work for me.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne - The `<title>` element works in Angular, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3nc1c). If it doesn't work for you, please provide a stackblitz showing the problem.

Comment: @ConnorsFan The stackblitz doesn't work for me. Could be a browser issue (I'm using Chrome 70 on Mac).

Comment: @KatharineOsborne - Strange. It works for me in Chrome 70 and Firefox, on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Ah, I was not hovering for long enough on the stackblitz. Also I'm using ngbtooltip, which does not work with the `<title>` method (apparently this method will create a div inside the svg which angular will not render).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem with ngbootstrap. It turns out that the tooltip creates a div, and if it is inside an svg, Angular will not render it. So my solution was to create a little html mask over the area of the svg where I wanted to trigger the tooltip.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <svg>
        <ellipse id="svg_2" cy="78.999999" cx="1042.499999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
    </svg>
    <div ngbTooltip="My tooltip" class="mytooltip" triggers="hover:blur click:blur focus:blur" [ngStyle]="{ 'left.px': leftPosition, 'top.px': topPosition }"></div>
</div>
```

Where `leftPosition` and `topPosition` are set dynamically in your `ts` file.

SCSS/CSS:

```
.mytooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; //whatever is a reasonable hit area
    height: 10px;
}
```

If your svg element placement is not dynamic, then you could just put it all in the style sheet. In my case, I had multiple tooltips I needed to attach to elements with varying widths and positions. You could also drop the class and add all the styling to `ngStyle`.

This method is probably not good for massively dynamic or interactive svgs, such as with D3.js, but that has it's own tooltip system anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the `svg` element in a `span` that has the tooltip:

```
<span ngbTooltip="This will show when I hover over this svg">
  <svg>
    <ellipse id="svg_2" cy="78.999999" cx="1042.499999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  </svg>
</span>
```