# How to make SVG elements accessible (in React)?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, accessibility

I am developing a React app using a bunch of `SVG` images/icons. They don't have visible texts but I want to show some tooltips on hover. What `attributes` and `sub-elements` should an accessible SVG element/component have? What is the React-friendly usage of SVGs?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10643426/19312729), you can use the [SVG <title> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title). But if you prefer a more react friendly way, I suggest you use an external library like [react-svg-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-tooltip).

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the mention of the previous post, both it and the previous answer are incomplete from my perspective. To truly maximize accessibility of SVG powered components, I recommend `<title>` and `<desc>`. Search engines, namely Google, will soon come to recognize that the description tag is also important in many cases.

This is from the [documentation of <desc>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/desc):

> The  element provides an accessible, long-text description of
> any SVG container element or graphics element.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "widgets" are keyboard accessible by setting `tabindex` to 0. Also check if they have proper roles. You can use the *Accessibility Tree* of your browser's dev tools.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles