# Hover-over in Batik generated SVG

Tags: awt, batik

I'm using Batik (svg-gen) to draw a svg (technical) diagram with the aid of java awt in a back-end service. I use this service on many places were the need arises to draw such diagram.

I would like to use a "tool-tip-kind-of-hover-over" to give more details on for instance a rectangle in the diagram.

Is this possible in Batik? I've found some hints on using css style but it strikes me as tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that its done by title, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic). In order to include the title tag, the Batik classes that generate SVG and relevant AWT classes can be extended.

To start:

```java
@Getter
public class TitledRectangle extends Rectangle {

    private String title;

    public TitledRectangle() {
    }

    public TitledRectangle(TitledRectangle r) {
        super( r );
        this.title = r.title;
    }
  // other constructors
}
```

And the corresponding batik class

```java
public class PDSvgTitledRectangle extends SVGRectangle {

    public PDSvgTitledRectangle(SVGGeneratorContext generatorContext) {
        super( generatorContext );
    }

    public Element toSVG(TitledRectangle rect) {
        Element element = super.toSVG( rect );
        if ( rect.getTitle() != null ) {
            Element svgTitle = super.generatorContext.getDOMFactory().createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title" );
            svgTitle.setTextContent( rect.getTitle() );
            element.appendChild( svgTitle );
        }
        return element;
    }

}
```

Now the new shape converter has to be used. That can be achieved by extending the SVGShape, responsible for writing the svg xml.

```java
public class PDSvgShape extends SVGShape {

    private PDSvgTitledRectangle titledRectangle;

    public PDSvgShape(SVGGeneratorContext generatorContext) {
        super( generatorContext );
        titledRectangle = new PDSvgTitledRectangle( generatorContext );
    }

    public Element toSVG(Shape shape) {
        if ( shape instanceof TitledRectangle ) {
            return this.titledRectangle.toSVG( (TitledRectangle) shape );
        }
        return super.toSVG( shape );
    }
}
```

And writing your own SVGGraphics2D (extending the existing one)

```java
public class PDSvgGraphics2D extends SVGGraphics2D {
    public PDSvgGraphics2D(Document domFactory) {
        super( domFactory );
        super.shapeConverter = new PDSvgShape( super.generatorCtx );
    }

    public PDSvgGraphics2D(Document domFactory, ImageHandler imageHandler, ExtensionHandler extensionHandler, boolean textAsShapes) {
        super( domFactory, imageHandler, extensionHandler, textAsShapes );
        super.shapeConverter = new PDSvgShape( buildSVGGeneratorContext( domFactory, imageHandler, extensionHandler ) );
    }

    public PDSvgGraphics2D(SVGGeneratorContext generatorCtx, boolean textAsShapes) {
        super( generatorCtx, textAsShapes );
        super.shapeConverter = new PDSvgShape( generatorCtx );
    }

    public PDSvgGraphics2D(PDSvgGraphics2D g) {
        super( g );
        super.shapeConverter = g.shapeConverter;
    }
}
```

Now, there's the possibility to use the newly created awt extension:

```java
 PDSvgGraphics2D g = new PDSvgGraphics2D( ctx, false );
 TitledRectangle rect = new TitledRectangle( x, y, w, h, "hello world!" ).
 g.draw( rectangle );
```